# How to run a task before running tests

Tags: scala, sbt

The following is a snippet from `Build.scala`:

```
object MyProject {

  val projectSettings = inConfig(Test)(
    testOptions += Tests.Setup { _ =>
      //subproject/runMain a.b.c.d.MainClass ??
    }
  }

}
```

I want to run a main class from another subproject before running tests. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```scala
// build.sbt
lazy val a = project.settings(
  testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup { _ =>
    (runMain in Compile in b).toTask(" b.Main arg1 arg2").value
  }
)

lazy val b = project
```

```scala
// b/src/main/scala/Main.scala
package b

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("hello " + args.mkString(" "))
  }
}
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!